# How to gather ritual components in a low-treasure campaign

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

In the campaign I play in, my character is the only magic user (Sorcerer). I just reached level 6 and decided it would be a good idea to take the ritual caster feat, to be able to help out the party. (This is tied into this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26594/how-do-i-prepare-a-permanent-magic-circle-for-the-linked-portal-ritual).)

However our DM is very inexperienced in running D&D (or RPGs in general) and has given us low amounts of treasure and enchanted items. Because of this my Sorcerer only has approximately 20gp to his name (and the rest of the party is in a similar state). Also most of the loot we have been able to get is geared towards the fighters and archers in our group.

With this I am curious to how I could best gain the required ritual Components. I have informed our DM of my interests in rituals to help him prepare for the coming sessions.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, at level 6, what gear do you have?

Comment: Very little. My Sorcerer only has leather armor and a staff as his implement. The rest of the group is not much better than I. Earlier in the campaign our DM unintentionally gave most of the group OP weapons(but not me) which he recently removed from the game(via a magic barrier require the player to be totally nude to pass through). Now we have a fort but no treasure and little gear.

Comment: He... is aware that by level 6, the monsters presented as part of the game assume that most of the party has +2 weapons (or at least nice +1 weapons), yes?

Comment: He creates his own monsters and enemies. Our group has taken on many challenges which we should have died but came out victorious.

Comment: You *can't* gather components, because in 4e components is just another word for money. Your DM broke one of the core mechanics of the game by giving you too little wealth, it should hardly be surprising that other associated mechanics don't function properly as a result.

Comment: As far as mechanics go, yes components is synonyms with money. However as far as story goes you could gather parts of magical beasts or rare plants to use. While the system measures cost, the DM could say "Blood of Unicorn" at 6 vials could be worth 500gp of Alchemic Components while "Sage of Tyme" is worth 10gp a sprig(Natural Components). It may not be able to cover costs as written, but with some house ruling the cost can be lowered.

Comment: If your character is so poor, how do you plan to master these rituals in the first place? Characters buy rituals for their ritual book, and I can't think of any ritual offhand that costs less than 100gp on the market.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**My answer: Talk to your DM about treasure expectations!**

Like 3E, 4E runs weird when you don't follow the Expected Wealth by Level.

If your DM agrees you should have more treasure, problem solved.

If your DM disagrees about that, find out why - if it is because he wants you to feel poor, he may be amenable to some house-ruling about how often you're allowed to use rituals. One house-rule I'm thinking right now is that each time you level up, you get one treasure parcel worth of Various Components that have no monetary value if sold but can be used, residium-like, for all rituals. That way you're still dirt poor but at least you can use your rituals.

If your DM doesn't agree with that either, retrain to a different feat because to answer you *actual* question: You cannot gather ritual components.

Comment: I might have to ask him about some house rules to balance rituals. I also know at our current location he has an easy point to implement such a rule like the package per level. May also need to have him looking into reducing costs also per casting(with some trade off of course).

Answer (score 5):

**Don't bother, if you must, take feats that allow you to perform rituals of a certain category for free once per day. Given your comment on not having *any* magical items at level 6, *really don't bother.***

Rituals are... strange. They exist for three meta-purposes: to shore up areas where the party is weak, to circumvent the plot, and to enable unusual plot. In almost all of these cases, they require what amounts to negotiation with the DM as to their use. (My DM tended to get very annoyed with my epic character when I tried to trivially route armies via [primal groves](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=288). At level 20+, the 4000 gp needed to create an entrance to a specific grove is *not even pocket change.* ) Money in 4e is a very very odd thing, more a component of character than aspect outside-of-character.

Therefore, don't bother trying to gather components. If you're severely undergeared, ritual prices will only make it worse. Instead, take either the vistani heritage ([Vistani Pathfinding](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2042), [Vistani Jongelur](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2040)) feats that allow mastery of certain schools, or the School Mastery (I recommend [Deception Mastery](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3707)). While travel and exploration are excellent ritual schools, their primary purpose is to get you around large swathes of uninteresting countryside, effectively allowing you to travel at the power of plot. From a depressingly pragmatic perspective, if you *don't* have it, the plot changes such that the distances are smaller.

Deception rituals are certainly interesting, but a challenge to DM, especially if your group goes for more standard dungeon crawls. Still, Deception Mastery is a fascinating thing to build one's character around.

As this is designed to power a series of portals, I recommend Vistani Heritage which gives you a vaguely interesting minor action power, and Vistani Pathfinding which:

> Benefit: You can master and perform exploration and travel rituals as though you had the Ritual Caster feat. Once per day, you can ignore the component cost of an exploration or travel ritual you have mastered of your level or lower.

Therefore, you can just cast linked portal for free, and at 15, create a teleportation circle for free, once per day.

Comment: While an interesting answer, it fails to help my current situation. In my linked question I have a specific purpose to taking the ritual caster feat, that this unfortunately does not help(or if it does I am unsure as I do not have a dndinsider account to find out). If you would be so kind to post excerpts to help me see the exact nature of your suggestions I may be able to see a way to use them.