# How do I prepare a permanent magic circle for the Linked Portal ritual?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, teleportation

In a previous [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26592/becoming-a-ritual-caster-in-a-custom-world) I asked about how to best gain components for Rituals in a world where magic is not as common.

In our last session we completely conquered a fort and decided to lay claim to it as our Base of Operations. However our quest needs us to leave for parts unknown shortly. As a new ritual caster (level 6) I would like to set up some rituals to help us in our travels and to let us return.

I have a general idea of what rituals I want to use to protect the fort, and others for ease of storage (should we find treasure hoards). But the one thing I am unclear on is how to set up an easy way to return once finished our quest.

I know I can master the Linked Portal Ritual at level 8 (if I can acquire it) but I don't believe our fort has a permanent magic circle. What steps could I take to prepare one (provided our DM allows it)?

Answer (score 4):

At level 15, you get access to the [Create Teleportation Circle](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=170) ritual or by GM fiat or by buying a scroll of this ritual:

> You create a teleportation circle with a unique sequence of magic sigils, which you and other ritual casters can useas a location marker for rituals such as Linked Portal and Planar Portal. The teleportation circle does not transport creatures anywhere on its own—it merely enables other travel rituals.

Which, if you maintain with a healing surge per day for a year, becomes permanent.

Beyond this, you are absolutely at the mercy of your DM.

Comment: For example, "at the mercy of your DM" could include hiring an NPC to perform and maintain the ritual, since you can hire an NPC for a ritual. The DM might send you on a quest to find him...